# How do I use \qquad

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am trying to make a work report in LaTeX, but is the first time I use it, so I find rather difficult.

How can I use `\qquad` multiple times, basically I need to use "tab" at certain times:

```
\qquad First text

\qquad Second text
```

When I compile it only the first text is "tab-ed" out the second text still starts from the border.

What can I do?

Comment: I think you should rather use something like the *verbatim* environment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting#Verbatim_text

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you find yourself in a situation that you need to insert spaces manually, 99% of times this indicates that something is deeply wrong. Can you give a bit more information of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, please post some of your code ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that))! Maybe locally modifying `\parindent` would be better